# Using variables in a vim shell command

Tags: variables, vim

How would I go about using a variable in a vim shell command (one done with `!`) in a vimscript? For instance, something kind of like this: (just an example, not what I'm really trying to do)

```
function Ls(dir)
    !ls a:dir
endfunction
```

Answer (score 47):

Use the `execute` command. Everything after it is an expression that evaluates to a string, which it then executes like a command you had typed in yourself.

```
function Ls(dir)
    execute '!ls ' . a:dir
endfunction
```

This says, "Evaluate the expression `'!ls ' . a:dir` and then execute it." The variable `a:dir` is expanded, the dot concatenates the two strings into `'!ls whatever'` and then that is executed as if you had typed it.